# SyntaxError: invalid syntax -- One line if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

My initial `if else` code is :

```
if response.get('fulfillments') is None:
    return (False, response)
else:
    return (True, response)
```

But I want to convert it to `one-line-if-else-statement`.

Here is what I am doing :

```
return (False, response) if response.get('fulfillments') is None else return (True, response)
```

But it is raising a syntax error, What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one-line `if-else` is not the same as the block.  It is an expression, not a statement or multiple statements.  You can't do something like:

```
(x = 4) if x > 5 else (x = 6)
```

Because those are statements.  Instead, it is like this:

```
x = (4 if x > 5 else 6)
```

Or in your case:

```
return (False, response) if response.get('fulfillments') is None else (True, response)
```

You don't really need the `if-else`, though.  Just do this:

```
return (response.get('fulfillments') is not None, response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Omit the second `return`. To simplify:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...    return True if x == 2 else False
```

read it as  "return the results of this ternary expression" not "return this thing in one case but return some other thing in another case"

Answer (score 2):

```
return (False, response) if response.get('fulfillments') is None else (True, response)
```

`val_positive if expression else val_negative`. val_positive or val_negative can't contain return statement